# Laravel with where eloquent builder. How to use db records values inside subquery?

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, relationship

I want to use a record fields in laravel eloquent subquery

I tried this

```
$clients = Client::with(['records' => function (Builder $query) {
   // how can i take a record fields there?
   $record = $query->first();
   $query->where('time', Carbon::now()->subMinutes(10 + $record->duration);
}])->where('profile_id', $profile->id)->get();
```

How can this be done?

Answer (score 0):

Just use the `use()`

```
$clients = Client::with(['records' => function (Builder $query) use ($record) {
   $query->where('time', Carbon::now()->subMinutes(10 + $record->duration);
}])->where('profile_id', $profile->id)->get();
```

Answer (score 0):

Your query is wrong. It is not possible to use the `$record` or `$query->first()` inside the `with` method. You will only be able to use those data only after the final `get()`. Since Eloquent will first fetch the data matching the `where` conditions except the "with" method, and then it will generate a query to fetch the eager-loaded relationships using `where in`.

You can achieve this query using a raw query, or like the other answer you have to fetch the `record` first and use that in the callback.

```php
       $clients = Client::with([
            'records' => function ($query) {
                $query->whereRaw("`time` = (10 + `duration`)");
            }
        ])
            ->where('profile_id', $profile->id)
            ->get();
```